# Missing the texture paint mode stencil mask overlay when in texture paint mode for an object (blender 2.8)

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting

In the tutorial series I'm watching the object the person is painting changes to "texture paint mode" where the object is flat shaded like this:

[image: texture paint mode in video]

However when I enter this mode my shading doesn't change, and instead looks like this:

[image: texture paint mode for me]

Which makes it hard to see which object I am currently painting. My texture paint opacity is at 100% and sliding it doesn't seem to make any difference in the scene like it did in the tutorial.

[image: texture paint opacity at 100%]

[image]

**EDIT** I decided to try and get it to work with a new file and it doesn't. I took the default cube and added a black texture. The object still shows in 3D and not flat, and the texture opacity slider does nothing. I can't replicate what the person had in the video.

Here is the new file with just the cube: 
[image]

And a screenshot of what it looks like for me in texture paint mode:

[image: Black cube still not showing the changed mode.]

Comment: Have you unwrapped your object? Given it an Image Texture node?

Comment: @moonboots yes the object is all unwrapped and there is a texture node hooked in to the BSDF node. I have since painted the object in flat mode which worked ok but still haven’t fixed the texture paint mode issue making it difficult to see the object I’m currently painting.

Comment: Could you please share your object or at least a part of it (one plank where the problem happens)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I have added it to the original post.

Comment: it looks like you didn't send the good object  ;)

Comment: @moonboots whoops, my bad. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pack the image. Anyway, I've created a new one. What you need is just to choose a brush with a higher *Strength* and another *Blend* mode. Also, be careful with your unwrapping, some faces are overlapping so when you paint on a part it will paint somewhere else. The easiest way, if you only paint in the 3D View, is to unwrap with *Smart UV Project*. If you also paint in the *Image Editor*, maybe mark seam and then choose the simple *Unwrap* mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but changing the strength or blend mode doesn't seem to make my selected object change like it does in your screenshot. It stays in the Studio style whereas in your image it seems to have gone flat shaded on the object you are painting.

Comment: maybe pack the image and share again

Comment: I have added the packed version in now. I really appreciate the help btw.

Comment: It seems to work fine, Lookdev display mode doesn't work on my system so I switch to Solid display mode, then select a plank, switch to Texture Paint, choose Blend > Mix, Strength > 1 and it paints

Comment: I have just added another file which is a blank black cube with a black texture to see if it was something weird with the file but it has the same issue. I have also now tried blender 2.81 but that hasn't helped either. I can paint perfectly fine, I just can't replicate the flat shading mode that seems to happen in the tutorial video I was watching.

Comment: By flat shading mode, I mean just for the selected object, not the whole scene, like in the video and in your screenshot.

Comment: I can't tell in Eevee mode because it bugs on my old system, but in Cycles your cube works fine, I can paint on it, if you plug the Image Texture node into the Principled BSDF and if you put a lamp like a sun it will display normally etc.

Comment: I'm not trying to get it to display normally, I want the selected object when in texture paint mode to be flat like in the video. I've been able to paint and render it all fine. Just trying to replicate the mode in the video where he selects an object and enters texture paint and that selected object is flat while the rest of the scene stays the same. I think it must be a bug or weird setting on my system. I can live without it but I'm just confused.

Comment: Ooh ok, well in my case it looks like in the video, are you in Solid display mode?

Comment: Yeah, though in the video it seems to work in all modes, not just solid.